# add string to every element of a python list

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a list made of a python dictionary keys via; `list(dict.keys())`.

```
dict.keys()
dict_keys(['South', 'North'])
```

I would like to add a string to the every element in the `list = ['South', 'North']` like:

`my_string = 'to_'`

In the end I want to have `list = ['to_South', 'to_North']`

Is there a method I could use for this?

something like:

```
list.add_beginning_of_each_element('to_')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Or `map`:

```
>>> l = ['South', 'North']
>>> list(map('to_'.__add__,l))
['to_South', 'to_North']
>>>
```

There a `add_prefix` in `pandas`, so if you have a pandas dataframe, you can just use `add_prefix` to add to the columns, an example of making a dataframe out of a list and having them as columns:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame(columns=['South', 'North']).add_prefix('to_').columns.tolist()
['to_South', 'to_North']
```

Comment: I was waiting for the minute

Comment: @oakca To solve the problem of the removed comment: `list(map((site+'-').__add__, l))`

Answer (score 14):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = ['South', 'North']
result = ['to_' + direction for direction in lst]
```

As an alternative you could use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
def add_to_beginning(s, start='to_'):
    return start + s

lst = ['South', 'North']

result = list(map(add_to_beginning, lst))
print(result)
```

Comment: nice one, but it is basically adding a string to each element with a for loop. I was looking for some build in function which would do the same thing, without a for loop?

Comment: @oakca You are going to need to have a loop *somewhere*, whether it is explicit or implicit. I'd rather have it explicit

Answer (score 4):

You can use lambda function:

```
lst = ['South', 'North']
result = list(map(lambda x: 'to_' + x, lst))
```

Comment: I need to add the string to the end of the list element, instead of the beginning, so lambda works, but __add__ doesn't

Answer (score 1):

`dict.keys()` does not return the actual keys, it merely returns a view (=copy) of the keys.

If you want to print a modified version of the keys:

```
print(['to_' + key for key in d.keys()])
```

If you want to change the actual keys:

```
d = {'to_' + key: value for key, value in d.items()}
```